# retrieving keys from dictionaries depending on value in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to find the most efficient way in python to create a dictionary of 'guids' (point ids in rhino) and retrieve them depending on the value(s) I assign them, change that value(s) and restoring them back in the dictionary. One catch is that with Rhinoceros3d program the points have a random generated ID number which I don't know so I can only call them depending on the value I give them.

are dictionaries the correct way? should the guids be the value instead of the keys?

a very basic example :

```
arrPts=[]
arrPts = rs.GetPoints()  # ---> creates a list of point-ids

ptsDict = {}
for ind, pt in enumerate(arrPts):
    ptsDict[pt] = ('A'+str(ind))

for i in ptsDict.values():
    if '1' in i :
        print ptsDict.keys()
```

how can I make the above code print the key that has the value '1' , instead of all the keys? and then change the key's value from 1 to e.g. 2 ?

any help also on the general question would be appreciated to know I'm in the right direction.

Thanks

Pav

Comment: When you say "change the key's value from 1 to 2, are there now two different `guid's` that have the same value (of 2) now?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dict.items()`.

An example:

```
In [1]: dic={'a':1,'b':5,'c':1,'d':3,'e':1}

In [2]: for x,y in dic.items():
   ...:     if y==1:
   ...:         print x
   ...:         dic[x]=2
   ...:         
a
c
e

In [3]: dic
Out[3]: {'a': 2, 'b': 5, 'c': 2, 'd': 3, 'e': 2}
```

`dict.items()` returns a list of tuples containing keys and value pairs in python 2.x:

```
In [4]: dic.items()
Out[4]: [('a', 2), ('c', 2), ('b', 5), ('e', 2), ('d', 3)]
```

and in python 3.x it returns an iterable view instead of list.

Comment: Oh yeah. long duration. Well, better to delete my answer, as you have covered all aspects. :)

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you want the GUID's to be values, not keys, since it looks like you want to look them up by something you assign.  ...but it really depends on your use case.

```
# list of GUID's / Rhinoceros3d point ids
arrPts = ['D20EA4E1-3957-11d2-A40B-0C5020524153', 
          '1D2680C9-0E2A-469d-B787-065558BC7D43', 
          'ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C']

# reference each of these by a unique key
ptsDict = dict((i, value) for i, value in enumerate(arrPts))
# now `ptsDict` looks like: {0:'D20EA4E1-3957-11d2-A40B-0C5020524153', ...}

print(ptsDict[1]) # easy to "find" the one you want to print 

# basically make both keys: `2`, and `1` point to the same guid 
# Note: we've just "lost" the previous guid that the `2` key was pointing to
ptsDict[2] = ptsDict[1]
```

**Edit:**

If you were to use a tuple as the key to your dict, it would look something like:

```
ptsDict = {(loc, dist, attr3, attr4): 'D20EA4E1-3957-11d2-A40B-0C5020524153',
           (loc2, dist2, attr3, attr4): '1D2680C9-0E2A-469d-B787-065558BC7D43',
           ...
          }
```

As you know, tuples are immutable, so you can't `change` the key to your dict, but you can remove one key and insert another:

```
oldval = ptsDict.pop((loc2, dist2, attr3, attr4))  # remove old key and get value
ptsDict[(locx, disty, attr3, attr4)] = oldval  # insert it back in with a new key
```

In order to have one key point to multiple values, you'd have to use a list or set to contain the guids:

```
{(loc, dist, attr3, attr4): ['D20E...', '1D2680...']}
```

Comment: hi Gerrat, thanks for your reply ! I didn't quite understand why should I make '2' and '1' point to the same guid. but in anycase, would I be able with your example to store more information in the keys than just a number? I have around 4 attributes I need to look through with various conditions and if met then to retrieve the guid.

Comment: @Pav: I'm not really "suggesting" you make them point to the same one - I'm just not sure exactly what you're trying to do.  You can certainly store more information in the keys than the number (see @Don's answer where he mentions using tuples).  With 4 attributes you need to look through, you should probably use a tuple as the key).  You mentioned wanting to `change` the keys value from 1 to 2 - that part is what a few of us are trying to understand what you mean by.

Comment: Hi gerratt again, each point has 4 values depending on location, distance from otherd and other attributes i should not bother u with. By those attributes i need to search and get the guids that match on what i want. But then these attributes change eg. Distance, location, so i need to update the keys. Hope im more clear. A tuple since correct but isnt it immutable? Meaning i cannot change them? Sorry for too much text, im new !

Comment: Also i think now i see what u mean by pointing on the same guid perhaps? Would python allow more than one similar keys to point to different values?